# Delete all remote files which does not exist locally with GIT

Tags: git, git-svn

I have lots of files on bitbucket which I do not have/anymore locally on my pc. I would like to delete them all in the next git push. What else git command do I have to execute to delete all remote files which does not locally exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Checkout what you have on bitbucket to your local machine.
2. Delete the files locally.
3. Commit your file deletions (git commit -a)
4. Push commit to bigbucket, they will be removed.

Comment: when I do git commit -a there is a list of old deleted files but how can I flag/check each file to be deleted with git push?

Comment: The git -a will delete all of them.  In your list you should see the ones that are staged and these will be deleted.

Comment: If you want to pick and choose, you can try git gui  (if you are on linux).